# Alt key shortcuts are not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04

I am new to linux. I had just installed ubuntu a couple of days ago. I'm using a Mac Layout DAS Keyboard.

My <kbd>Alt</kbd> key short cuts where working fine yesterday. I could navigate applications with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> just fine, but today it is no longer working. When I went online to a website that shows what keys I'm pressing I can see the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key being recognized, but when I go to record a keyboard shortcut in the system settings it does not recognize the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key being pressed.

I did spend some time changing the keyboard layout with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and swapped the `super` and `ctrl` keys to make it more "mac like" I don't recall experiencing the issue after I had done those things, but I could be wrong.

I searched google up and down google for an answer, but could not figure it out.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

any suggestions are greatly appreciated